# Facebook integration with my app in android

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook account with my app.buy i am getting Error
App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.

Here is my logcat

```
03-23 14:19:57.784: E/Package Name=(10548): com.pcs.sliderringtineproj
03-23 14:19:57.854: E/Key Hash=(10548): UkWsiQcnfXkYq9BLp4yzhmhcnbk=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to explain the issue: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10201756195602898

You need to make it public by going to your app in the developer console, click on Status & review and check yes for public.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.Class

```
package com.example.facebooklogin;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MainFragment mainFragment;
private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
        .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}


}
```

MainFragment.Class(For Facebook)

```
package com.example.facebooklogin;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton)  view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email",
            "user_location"));

    authButton.setFragment(this);

    return view;
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        makeMeRequest(session);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
    // Make an API call to get user data and define a
    // new callback to handle the response.
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                /*
                 * @Override public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response
                 * response) { // If the response is successful if (session ==
                 * Session.getActiveSession()) { if (user != null) { // Set the
                 * id for the ProfilePictureView // view that in turn displays
                 * the profile picture. Log.e("user",user.toString()); } } if
                 * (response.getError() != null) { // Handle errors, will do so
                 * later. } }
                 */

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("user", user.toString());
                    Log.e("username", user.getName());
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

Comment: before this please setup your key hashes. follow this links : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#create_hash . Setup your manifest file by providing the App_ID